# The moment of inertia of two rods joined at the center forming a cross about the $x$-axis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

So I have two rods that are equal in mass and length. I join them together and form a cross. What is the moment of inertia of this object now in the $x$ axis?

So I attached an image, where the red line shows the axis of rotation. So at that axis, what is the moment of inertia of the cross?

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Gert I do not even know from where to start actually

Comment: The MMOI of the rod along the axis is ZERO so you are left with the MMOI of a rod about its center, the most basic of calculations, $\frac{m}{12} \ell^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your rod is treated as very thin, or radius of cross-section is :$r\rightarrow0$, then rod along x-axis isn't really hindering (providing inertia) to rotational motion. So here only moment of inertia of other rod about centre will be counted.

Now if your rod is treatable as cylinders, then you would have to individually find moment of inertias of both cylinders about your x-axis (calculus will be required), and then add them to get final moment of inertia

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Welcome! If you are new, you can upvote answers/questions which you find useful, and can select answers which you think are best by clicking tick button.

Comment: So I know that the inertia of a rod about center is simply 1/12 ml^2. Also, the inertia of a rod around axis is 1/2 ml^2. So does this mean that the inertia of the whole thing would be the inertias added? Check this out for what I mean: https://cdn.kastatic.org/ka-perseus-images/856e0e3eeefc09667caaddc48ede19f1873302d1.png

Comment: What do you mean by 'around axis'?

Comment: So around the x-axis. Please check out the image that I linked :)

Comment: You mean about axis which has $I=\frac{1}{2}mr^2$?

Comment: Exactly! :) And then also the other rod which has I = 1/12 mr^2

Comment: Wait, you are confusing. If you meant rod is to be treated like rod only then there is no meaning of $I$, about the axis. And you will treat other rod, like rod only. So $I_f=1/12mr^2$ On other hand treating rod like  cylinder, you will get $I_1=1/2mr^2$ for cylinder across the x axis. For other cylinder you would have to find $I_2$ manually. $I_{\text{final}}=I_1+I_2$

Comment: Wait sorry to bother you but I am talking about the rods, not cylinders. Both formulas in the image are for the same rod. So it gives the inertia of the rod rotated in the x-axis when it is parallel to it, and the other rod rotated in the x-axis when it is perpendicular to the axis. Therefore, the inertia when the rods are joined to make a cross would be 1/12 mr^2 + 1/2 mr^2, right?

Comment: Yeah ok so I got to know your confusion. Actually in image about $I$ for rod about axis is actually *cylinder*. You see rod is in idealistic sense is just a 1 dimensional line. So $I$ about axis along our rod is meaningless. Think of it. You can't rotate line in same way you are rotating cylinder about that axis. Cylinder is a 3d object so it can rotate meaningfully and provides inertia. So in this case, rod along x axis don't provide any moment of inertia.

Comment: aaaa that makes so sense! Thank you so much! So if both of them were cylinders, then the inertia of the whole thing would be 1/12 mr^2 + 1/2 mr^2, right?

Comment: Welcome again! Actually moment of inertia for cylinder perpendicular to axis wouldn't be same as for rod $1/12mr^2$. Again because of cylinder is 3d and rod is 1d, both have different kind of mass distribution. Here you need calculus to find moment of inertia. Other cylinders moment of inertia is of course $1/2mr^2$.